# How to sum values that all have the same beginning in R

Tags: r, vector, syntax, sum

Suppose I have created 3 values in R

```
brice1 <- 55
brice2 <- 10
brice3 <- brice1 * brice2
```

I now want to sum all of them.

```
brice_total <- brice1 + brice2 + brice3
```

BUT, I don't want to type out every variable.  How would I tell R to sum all variables that begin with "Brice".  For instance, in STATA a * indicates an ambiguous ending, so I could do something like

```
egen brice_total = sum(brice*)
```

I need to do the same thing in R because I need to sum a long list of values that all start with the same string of characters.

Comment: @akrun has a good answer for this. I would recommend storing values in a list object rather than your global environment. `R` has a lot of tools for working efficiently on lists.

Answer (score 1):

We can get values of all the objects with names that starts (`^`) with 'brice' followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) till the end of the string (`$`) in a `list` and `Reduce` with `+` to get the sum in `base R`

```
Reduce(`+`, mget(ls(pattern = '^brice\\d+$')))
```

Comment: very nice, I appreciate it

Comment: @bricevk if you found this solution helpful and/or it answered your question please read this: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).